# How to know what wallet a Bitcoin transaction is at now

Tags: transactions, theft

I have a question. Someone has taken/stolen bitcoin from me and I can see this transaction:
https://blockstream.info/address/1HFea6fugbV5cRG3dCgFgiDWtJL1xiTkki

How can I track to what bitcoin wallet and where that wallet is registered at?
With other words where does those 0.39 BTC exists now and how to know under what company that wallet is registered at?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

> **How can I track to what bitcoin wallet**

You cannot.

> **and where that wallet is registered at?**

You cannot tell from the address alone,

Wallets are not "registered", anyone can download wallet software and run it on their phone or computer without registering with any organisation, without notifying any organisation, without creating an account.

Some businesses do offer wallet services where they create accounts for customers which they also call "wallets". So far as the Bitcoin network is concerned,  the Bitcoin shown is owned by the business, not by customers of that business. These types of wallet are called custodial-wallets because the business is the custodian of the money. In these cases, the customer really just has an IOU, they don't have money. Tracing movements of money in custodial wallets can only be done by those custodial businesses. You cannot identify the business from the address alone. If the business re-uses a deposit address for all its customers then other customers might recognize when someone else has paid money to the same business, but I doubt many businesses fail to change and rotate addresses to combat this.

> **With other words where does those 0.39 BTC exists now**

No one really knows anything useful about this. This is the way Bitcoin was deliberately designed. It was intended that banks, governments and other organisations or individuals not be able to track or control Bitcoin. It was intended that Bitcoin be at least as anonymous and untraceable as conventional forms of cash. More so since Bitcoin doesn't have serial-numbers on banknotes.

The money you refer to was moved to 2 other addresses on 20th February

```
Hash     ae883ed70a09c9d2c2958fae2d177edfb49ca34d3ed158afed1ece19c3d1e497

From     1HFea6fugbV5cRG3dCgFgiDWtJL1xiTkki     0.39325252 BTC

To       37iCSADB6UMLf8FPLmWMBzFXY6g5dcG9gZ     0.16533000 BTC
         1CupwRfjYVe8gunFVv1jAGSGyziG46Pow      0.22778632 BTC
         Fee                                    0.00013620 BTC     
                                               ---------------
                                               -0.39325252 BTC
```

This looks like a normal spend, where some money is sent to another person or business and change is returned to the owner of the money. A different return address is normally used for privacy reasons.

> **and how to know under what company that wallet is registered at?**

You cannot find this out from the address or transaction details alone.